# Correllation (pandas) between integer and boolean?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, correlation

I have my data in the form of:

```
price | bool_qual_1 | bool_qual_2 | bool_qual_3
13000 |        True |        True |        True
20000 |       False |        True |        True
15000 |        True |        True |       False
13000 |       False |       False |       False
15000 |        True |        True |        True
```

In other words, my `price` attribute has 3 boolean qualities.

How do I find the correlation between my `price` and each of my qualities?

I am aware of df.corr() which uses pearson correlation but does this value make sense between integer and boolean?

Comment: Would the correlation make sense if `True = 1` and `False = 0`?

Comment: That's my question, I'm not sure ?

Comment: The short answer is yes, it makes sense. In Python (and most/all of computer science), `True=1` and `False=0`. One-hot encoding transforms categorical variables into 1s and 0s by creating columns for each categorical variable. In the case of your data, that's already done. `df.corr()` returns the correlation between price and each of your columns. You could make the substitution I mentioned before and your results wouldn't change.

Comment: Why are trying to find the correlation? Is it because you are trying to predict whether one of the booleans will be true or false based on the price? If that's what you're trying to do, you may be better off using classification techniques, e.g. logistic regression rather than simple correlation, or an actual classifier like KNN, a Decision Tree or Random Forest, SVM, etc. If what you're trying to do is predict whether the boolean will be True or False let me know and I can provide more detail. Scikit-learn makes it very easy to get started with classifiers.

Answer (score 3):

As some people in comments have already suggested: just replace "True" with 1 and "False" with 0. **However** there are a couple of things you should be aware of as you do:

1. For this task you'll be able to use "Pearson correlation coefficient" only, as "Kendall Tau" and "Spearman rank" coefficients were created for rankable correlation and would likely result in a random/wrong answer. To use Pearson correlation coefficient in pandas simply write:

   `df.corr(method ='pearson')`
2. As `price` varies havily and columns `bool_qual_*` do not (they are only 0 or 1 now) you should expect correlation coefficient's value to be on the lower side.